# Error while trying to upload file in sharepoint

Tags: python, sharepoint

I'm trying to **upload** image file in **sharepoint** via basic authentication in python. The below code gives **403 forbidden error**:

```
import requests

# SharePoint site and document library URL
sharepoint_url = 'https://something.sharepoint.com/sites/something
document_library_url = f'{sharepoint_url}/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?something..'

# SharePoint credentials
username = config['sharepoint_cred']['username']
password = config['sharepoint_cred']['password']

# Local file path of the plot
local_file_path = 'my_plot.png'

# Authenticate with SharePoint
auth = requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth(username, password)

# Upload the file to SharePoint
with open(local_file_path, 'rb') as file:
    upload_url = f'{document_library_url}/{local_file_path}'
    response = requests.put(upload_url, data=file)

print(response.status_code)
print(response)
# Check the response status
if response.status_code == 200:
    print('Plot uploaded to SharePoint successfully.')
else:
    print('Failed to upload the plot to SharePoint.')
```

If I try to use `Office365-REST-Python-Client` then the error is `from office365.sharepoint.files.file_creation_information import FileCreationInformation` could not be resolved.

```
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.files.file_creation_information import FileCreationInformation

# SharePoint site and document library URL
sharepoint_url = 'https://something.sharepoint.com/sites/something'
document_library_relative_url = '/sites/something'

# SharePoint credentials
username = config['sharepoint_cred']['username']
password = config['sharepoint_cred']['password']

# Local file path of the plot
local_file_path = 'my_plot.png'

# Authenticate with SharePoint

ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(sharepoint_url)
if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username, password):
    ctx = ClientContext(sharepoint_url, ctx_auth)

    # Get the document library
    target_folder = ctx.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_url(document_library_relative_url)

    # Prepare the file creation information
    file_info = FileCreationInformation()
    file_info.content = open(local_file_path, 'rb')
    file_info.url = local_file_path
    file_info.overwrite = True

    # Upload the file
    uploaded_file = target_folder.files.add(file_info)
    ctx.execute_query()

    print('Plot uploaded to SharePoint successfully.')
else:
    print('Failed to authenticate with SharePoint.')
```

Answer (score 1):

For user name and password, you can use following code to connect sharepoint

```
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from tests import test_site_url, test_username, test_password

ctx = ClientContext(test_site_url).with_user_credentials(test_username, test_password)
web = ctx.web.get().execute_query()
print(web.url)
```